# Copy Groups from one user to another in AD, except one specific group

Tags: windows, powershell, active-directory, command

Need help with adding a small comand to finish this pwoershell command.
I have this powershell command that copy groups from one user to another.
Now what i need is to add a command that will "Except" a specific group, like it will copy all the groups except one specific group.

Thanks for help.

```
Get-ADUser -Identity $Oldusername -Properties memberof | Select-Object -ExpandProperty memberof | Add-ADGroupMember -Members $Newusername
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Get-ADUser -Identity $Oldusername -Properties memberof | Select-Object -ExpandProperty memberof | Where-Object { $_ -NotMatch $grouptoexclude } | Add-ADGroupMember -Members $Newusername
```

`$grouptoexclude` containing the name of the group you don't want the new user to be added into. It must be a distinguished name like `CN=GroupName,OU=Groups,OU=Users & Workstations,DC=Fabrikam,DC=COM`

Comment: Thanks, that what i needed :)